# How to choose a font size for making a glyph texture in canvas2d

Tags: javascript, canvas, fonts, webgl

I'd like use Canvas2D to make a glyph texture for WebGL. A glyph texture is a texture full of letters that you use to render text.

The problem I'm running into is I can't see, given the Canvas API, how to do this in a cross platform "good" way. What do I mean? Well for example if I was using some old 8bit font where I knew each character was 8x8 pixels exactly, then I'd know if I wanted say 32 glyphs I'd need a texture some multiple of 32 8x8 cells. Like say 256x8 or 128x16 or 64x32 etc.. I'd put the character for each glyph in each cell and be done.

Unfortunately I can't see any good way to figure out the size of letter using the canvas2D api without a ton of work.

For example: Let's say I want 8x16 EGA like glyphs. Well let's check. I tell the browser I want an "8px monospace" font.

```
var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "8px monospace";
var dim = {
  minWidth: 100,
  maxWidth: 0,
};
for (var ii = 33; ii < 128; ++ii) {
  var letter = String.fromCharCode(ii);
  var t = ctx.measureText(letter);
  dim.minWidth = Math.min(t.width, dim.minWidth);
  dim.maxWidth = Math.max(t.width, dim.maxWidth);
}
console.log(dim);
```

It prints

```
// Object {minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 4.80078125}
```

That's clearly not what I want. On top of that AFAICT the size of the font is browser and platform dependent. I'm not even sure if I use my own font if that guarantees what size the glyphs will be rendered for a given font size specification.

One way is to try different sizes, measure their characters, then pick the closest match. That sounds very inefficient.

Another would maybe to just pick a size and render all of the character and just use them the size they are scaling when used in WebGL. In this case though picking "8px monospace" would make a pretty ugly font, at least in Chrome. I can iterate until I find something that looks good but then I have no idea if it will look good in another browser or on another platform.

Is there some official way to know the size a font will render so if you want to make glyphs you can? Or is there some other reference for how to do this in general? Like how a non-browser native app would deal with this.

I suppose for most native apps you'd just let the user pick a font size and then clip or wrap when you run out of space. But for a game you often need your text to fit in some specifically sized space and so you need to pick a font that will fit that space well and there in seems to be the issue.

BTW: this question came up making [this article about text in WebGL](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-text-glyphs.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend using canvas2d for that at all (edit : because canvas2d is terrible at everything glyph-related, not limited to being unable to figure out the height of a glyph, it  *inevitably* leads to a ton of work. ) . In my opinion either SVG or, depending on your preferences, HTML both are quite good at everything font-related and CSS makes it really easy to adjust all those dozens of font related options and metrics.

I think ( but don't know with 100% certainty ) all major browsers support rasterizing svg to texture through data uri.

```
let img = new Image();
img.src = `data:image/svg+xml,
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="128" height="128">
        <!-- some grid layout with inlined styles -->
    </svg>
`;
 img.onload = function ( loadedTexture) { ... }
```

(if you want to use html it apparently has to be valid xhtml embedded into the svg in a `<foreignObject>` tag. I don't know what's up with that. )

edit : added [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/34nahq8h/1/) using basically just `HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect()` to measure the glyphs and render any font, not just the monospace font family. One potential pitfall : you *need* to explicitly set a font it may happen that it renders a *different* font to the texture. TT

```js
var img = new Image;

img.src = "data:image/svg+xml,"+glyphSource.outerHTML;

img.onload = function( ) {
    document.body.appendChild( img );
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvas.height = 128;
    
    document.body.appendChild( canvas );
    var container = glyphSource.children[0].children[0];
    
    

    var glyphs = [].slice.call( container.children );
    var cR = glyphs[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var minY = cR.top;
    var minX = cR.left;
    var w = 128;
    var h = 128;
    
    const SIZE = 128;
    const DIM = .25;
    
    var glyphUV = glyphs.map( function( glyph ) {
        var d = glyph.getBoundingClientRect();
        //sampling upside down
       
        return [ 
            d.left,d.top,
            d.right,d.top,  
            d.left,d.bottom,
            d.left,d.bottom,
            d.right,d.top,
            d.right,d.bottom
        ];
    });
    
    const GLYPH_ENUM = {};
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890".split("")
    .forEach( function ( letter, index ) { GLYPH_ENUM[ letter ] = index } );
    console.log( "a",glyphs[ GLYPH_ENUM[ "m" ] ].getBoundingClientRect() );
    var posArr = [];
    var uvArr = [];
    var totalLength = 0;
    var SCALE = 2;
    function writeString( str ) {        
        var offX = 0;
        var offY = 0;
        str.split("").forEach( function( letter ) {
            var letterIndex = GLYPH_ENUM[ letter ];
            var r = glyphs[ letterIndex ].getBoundingClientRect();
            posArr.push(
                offX, offY,
                offX + r.width, offY,
                offX, offY + r.height,
                offX, offY + r.height,
                offX + r.width, offY,
                offX + r.width, offY + r.height
            );
            offX += r.width;
            totalLength++;
            uvArr.push.apply( uvArr, glyphUV[ letterIndex ] );
        });
    };
    writeString("Textrendering");

    window.gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    var program = gl.createProgram();
    var fs = gl.createShader( gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER );
    
    gl.shaderSource( fs, `
        precision mediump float;
        varying vec2 texCoord;
        uniform sampler2D glyphs;
        void main ( void ) {
            vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy;
            gl_FragColor = texture2D( glyphs, texCoord );
        
        }
    `);
    gl.compileShader( fs );
    
    if (! gl.getShaderParameter( fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS ) ) 
        return console.warn( gl.getShaderInfoLog( fs ) );
    
    var vs = gl.createShader( gl.VERTEX_SHADER );
    gl.shaderSource( vs, `
        attribute vec2 pos;
        attribute vec2 uv;
        varying vec2 texCoord;
        #define SCALE 2.5
        void main ( void ) {
            vec2 p = ( pos / vec2( ${w}, ${h} ) * SCALE - 1. ) * vec2( 1, -1);
            gl_Position = vec4( p, 0, 1 );
            texCoord = ( 
                uv - vec2( ${minX}, ${minY} ) 
            ) / vec2( ${w}, ${h} );
        }
    ` );
    gl.compileShader( vs );
    
    if (! gl.getShaderParameter( vs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS ) ) 
        return console.warn( gl.getShaderInfoLog( vs ) );
    
    gl.attachShader( program, vs );
    gl.attachShader( program, fs );
    gl.linkProgram( program );
    
    var tex0 = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex0 );

    gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img );
    console.log( img.width, img.height );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST );  
    //gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST );  
    
    var pos = gl.createBuffer( );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pos );
    
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(
        posArr                  
    ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, gl.FLOAT, 0, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( 0 );
    var uv = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uv );
    var a = 8;
    var b = 8+14;
    
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(
        uvArr
    ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( 1, 2, gl.FLOAT, 0, 0, 0 );
     gl.enableVertexAttribArray( 1 );
    
    gl.clearColor( .5, .5, .5, 1 );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.useProgram( program );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6*totalLength );
   
    glyphSource.style.display = "none";
    img.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<svg id="glyphSource" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="128" height="128" style="background:#CCC;">
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%" style="">
        <div xmlns= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font:15px Helvetica;">
            <span>A</span>
            <span>B</span>
            <span>C</span>
            <span>D</span>
            <span>E</span>
            <span>F</span>
            <span>G</span>
            <span>H</span>
            <span>I</span>
            <span>J</span>
            <span>K</span>
            <span>L</span>
            <span>M</span>
            <span>N</span>
            <span>O</span>
            <span>P</span>
            <span>Q</span>
            <span>R</span>
            <span>S</span>
            <span>T</span>
            <span>U</span>
            <span>V</span>
            <span>W</span>
            <span>X</span>
            <span>Y</span>
            <span>Z</span>
            <span>a</span>
            <span>b</span>
            <span>c</span>
            <span>d</span>
            <span>e</span>
            <span>f</span>
            <span>g</span>
            <span>h</span>
            <span>i</span>
            <span>j</span>
            <span>k</span>
            <span>l</span>
            <span>m</span>
            <span>n</span>
            <span>o</span>
            <span>p</span>
            <span>q</span>
            <span>r</span>
            <span>s</span>
            <span>t</span>
            <span>u</span>
            <span>v</span>
            <span>w</span>
            <span>x</span>
            <span>y</span>
            <span>z</span>
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
            <span>4</span>
            <span>5</span>
            <span>6</span>
            <span>7</span>
            <span>8</span>
            <span>9</span>
            <span>0</span>
        </div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your code does not appear to answer the question (!?).

Comment: @markE sorry, you're right, I forgot the most important part.

Comment: I agree with you in general that it's best not to do text yourself but sometimes you need text in your 3D scene, like say labeling buildings and wanting building that are obscured to have their labels obscured as well. Or putting names above avatars in a 3D MMO

Comment: @gman maybe it's a misunderstanding, rendering fonts in webgl makes total sense. I recommended not using canvas2d to create the texture atlas, and instead using svg / html with css for that.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how that helps though. How do I know the size of the glyphs in the SVG image? I guess I can specifically design an SVG on the fly that puts the glyphs in a grid of my desired size? But I guess that only works if the characters are monospaced. If I want to create glyphs for a proportional font how does SVG help? Is there SVG api for better measurements?

Comment: BTW: [Made a sample using SVG for texture](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/wjoh38f3/). Chrome, Firefox, and Safari seemed to work, at least on OSX

Comment: @gman Ok I managed to hack together a simple example how it could be implemented ( it's a very similar technique those fancy canvas layout engines use ). Took me *way longer than expected™*